# How can I change color scheme when checkbox is checked?

Tags: html, css, sass, color-scheme, scss-mixins

I am trying to implement dark and light mode for my website. It should be loaded based on `prefers-color-scheme` and than user should be able to toggle between these two mods.

I have written this:

```html
<div id="theme-togle">
    <input id="theme-toggle-dark" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="checkmark-dark"></span>
    <input id="theme-toggle-light" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="checkmark-light"></span>
</div>
```

```css
@mixin dark-theme {
    --body-color:           #313131;
    --text-color:           #FFFFFF;
    --title-color:          #000000;
    --subtitle-color:       #808080;
    --logo-color:           #FFFFFF;
    --link-color:           #FFFFFF;
    --link-visited-color:   #FFFFFF;
    --quote-color:          #FFFFFF;
    --code-background-color:#787878;
    --text-highlight-color: #D3D3D3;
    --separator-color:      #525252;
}


@mixin light-theme {
    --body-color:           #313131;
    --text-color:           #FFFFFF;
    --title-color:          #000000;
    --subtitle-color:       #808080;
    --logo-color:           #FFFFFF;
    --link-color:           #FFFFFF;
    --link-visited-color:   #FFFFFF;
    --quote-color:          #FFFFFF;
    --code-background-color:#787878;
    --text-highlight-color: #D3D3D3;
    --separator-color:      #525252;
}

:root{
    @include light-theme;
}


#theme-toggle-dark {
    display: none;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark){
    @include dark-theme;

    #theme-toggle-light {
        display: none;
    }

    #theme-toggle-dark {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light){
    :root{
        @include light-theme;
    }

    .theme-toggle-dark {
        display: none;
    }

    .theme-toggle-light {
        display: block;
    }
}

#theme-toggle-dark:checked + :root{
    @include dark-theme;
}

#theme-toggle-light:checked + :root{
    @include light-theme;
}
```

It can successfully select default mode based on `prefers-color-scheme`, but I am not able to make it toggle with checkbox.

How Can I achieve that ? I am looking for javascript free solution.

Thank you for help

Comment: `:root` is not an immediate sibling of the checkbox, so your selector `#theme-toggle-dark:checked + :root` will not work.

Comment: @Terry Is there a way to write it right ?

Comment: You will need to use JS for that.

Comment: @TerryWhy does it work for this guy ? https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-enable-dark-mode-on-your-website-with-pure-css-32640335474 Am I missing something ? I can not figure out how my and his cases are different.

Comment: Read the selectors that he's using: `... + *`, which means he's selecting ALL immediate siblings and applying the CSS variables to. Your approach is different.

Comment: For now there is no way to do it except with JS. In the future you will be able to do it only with CSS if `:has` is [supported by the navigators](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) like `body:has(#theme-toggle-dark:checked) {@include dark-theme;} body:has(#theme-toggle-light:checked) {@include dark-theme;}`

Comment: I strongly suggest reusable classes rather than IDs wherever possible in CSS. Also, you have a typo in your markup: `theme-togle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to reorganize your HTML in order to get it to work.

Currently, you have the checkboxes as a child node of the body element, which is inside the `:root` element. That causes your selector to fail because you are using the direct sibling syntax. You won't be able to use `:root` either.

In order for it to work, your checkbox will need to be the first child inside the body element and then you'd need to apply selectors to everything else.

```html
<body>
    <input id="theme-toggle-dark" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="checkmark-dark"></span>
    <input id="theme-toggle-light" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="checkmark-light"></span>

    ...
</body>
```

```css
#theme-toggle-dark:checked ~ * {
    @include dark-theme;
}

#theme-toggle-light:checked ~ * {
    @include light-theme;
}
```

That said, this is not really an ideal solution, because re-painting all nodes with the asterisk selector can be relatively taxing depending on the amount of content in your page.

It may be best to wrap all of your content in one container element and only do the application to that:

```html
<body>
    <input id="theme-toggle-dark" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="checkmark-dark"></span>
    <input id="theme-toggle-light" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="checkmark-light"></span>

    <div id="container">
       ...
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
#theme-toggle-dark:checked ~ #container {
    @include dark-theme;
}

#theme-toggle-light:checked ~ #container {
    @include light-theme;
}
```

Also, you probably want to use a `radio` input instead of a checkbox. It wouldn't make sense to have both items selected.

Alternatively, you might consider only using one checkbox as a toggle switch. This way you don't have to keep track of the default user preference state (which would have to be done via JavaScript).

Here is an example of how it might work:

```html
<body>
    <input id="theme-toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <span id="checkmark-theme"></span>

    <div id="container">
       ...
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
   #container {
       @include dark-theme;
   }

   #theme-toggle:checked ~ #container {
       @include light-theme;
   }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
   #container {
       @include light-theme;
   }

   #theme-toggle:checked ~ #container {
       @include dark-theme;
   }
}
```

Here is a working example. Note: you'll need to do some clever sizing and positioning in order to get everything lined up. You'll probably need to replicate some of styling for the toggle label as well.

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
   #container {
      background: black;
      color: white;
   }
   
   #toggle:checked ~ #container {
      background: white;
      color: black;
   }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
   #container {
      background: white;
      color: black;
   }
   
   #toggle:checked ~ #container {
      background: black;
      color: white;
   }
}
```

```html
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
<label for="toggle">Toggle Theme</label>
<div id="container">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for awesome answer. I will try to implement that asap. If I understand it correctly, would need to use two radio buttons ? I hoped that there would be one button which I can use to toggle between color schemes.

Comment: Personally, I would probably use a single checkbox that toggles dark mode on or off.

Comment: If you do that in your answer I will accept it right away before I try to implement it.

Comment: I added a third example to show how it could be done with a single checkbox as a toggle switch for inverting the preferred-color-scheme.

Comment: I have implemented your answer. It chooses right color scheme as default, but it does not toggle when checkbox is clicked. Does it work in your example ? Have you tried it ?

Comment: Yes, I have added a working example. It is not perfect and you'll need to do some more work on your own based on your design, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234446/discussion-between-jan-cerny-and-jeff-jenkins).